# Not Serializable Exception

Tags: exception, jsp, serialization, vector

i am trying to create a mock shopping cart for a uni project. im using two java classes Item and shoppingCart, shopping cart uses a vector to store Items and then writes them to a file. i am trying to use the classes on a jsp page but when i try to write to the file i get an java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: cart.Item... any ideas how i could fix this??

Answer (score 2):

From the javadoc on NotSerializableException... "Thrown when an instance is required to have a Serializable interface."

This means that your class that you're serializing need to implement the Serializable marker interface.

Comment: You could add that it needs a 'serialVersionUID' in order to be Serializable.

Comment: i have tried implementing Serializable on both classes with no luck

Comment: Does Item contain any members that are not serializable? Otherwise, I'd double-check that you are indeed implementing java.io.Serializable.

As for serialVersionUID, you should have that, but it won't result in NotSerializableException if you do not provide it (the runtime will auto-calculate the version ID when needed).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small Example to you...

```
import java.io.*;

class player implements Serializable{
    String name;
    double health;
    double positionX;
    double positionY;
    int weapon;     
}


class game{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        player character1 = new player();
        character1.name = "Inukz";
        character1.health = 82.62;
        character1.positionX = 80;
        character1.positionY = 33;
        character1.weapon = 2;

        player character2 = new player();
        character2.name = "Prasad";
        character2.health = 32.62;
        character2.positionX = 40;
        character2.positionY = 63;
        character2.weapon = 3;


        player character3 = new player();
        character3.name = "Thilan";
        character3.health = 12.62;
        character3.positionX = 10;
        character3.positionY = 83;
        character3.weapon = 1;



        FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream("myGame.js",true);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);

        os.writeObject(character1);


        os.close();


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid NotSerializableException make sure:

1. **your class** implements Serializable
2. all non primitive **members** implement Serializable (or are transient instead)
3. if your class is an **inner class** it's either static or the outer class implements
   Serializable

Besides that you also need to define **serialVersionUID** for every Serializable class. Check all 3 cases above plus:

1. all Serializable **superclasses**
2. if your class is an **anonymous class**, define it there too

Note: your code may run without serialVersionUID sometimes but [read the last paragraph in Serializable's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) to understand why it will be a problem depending on the environment.

---

There's a VM option to add details to the exception. It shows the root and nested classes failing to serialize:

```
-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true
```